# Android, using a non-installed(phone) language

Tags: android, locale, multilingual

**EDIT**
I was working with the Indonesian language, it seems this is an Java "Issue" which actually requires you to use the values-in folder.
**/EDIT**

I ran into a "bug" today while working on multiple languages.
It seems that you cannot force the use of a locale if it's not installed on a phone (Using this mostly for translations).

In our app we want to force the use of a certain language sometimes people who use this are moderators who work in multiple languages, so when adding the indonesian language I noticed the locale can't be set unless you have it installed so my values-id is not being used.

I'm currently using this code to fetch the translation (and have a fallback to english if the translation would be empty however this doesn't occur anymore).

Is there any way I could force the use of the values-id file (or other languages in that case).

```
try {//try to fetch it, if we're good boys we added it and it'll be no problem
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            String str = res.getString(res.getIdentifier(text, "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName));

        if (str.equals("") && GlobalVars.globalCurrentLanguage != "en"){
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.setToDefaults();   // That will set conf.locale to null (current locale)
            // We don't want current locale, so modify it
            conf.locale = new Locale("");   // Or conf.locale = Locale.ROOT for API 9+
            // or conf.setLocale(Locale.ROOT) for API 14+
            // Since we need only strings, we can safely set metrics to null
            Resources rsrcDflt = new Resources(context.getAssets(), null, conf);
            str = rsrcDflt.getString(res.getIdentifier(text, "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName)); // Got it at last!
            conf.locale = new Locale(GlobalVars.globalCurrentLanguage);
            rsrcDflt = new Resources(context.getAssets(), null, conf);
            rsrcDflt.getString(res.getIdentifier(text, "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName)); // Got it at last!
        }

        return str;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //oh dearie we forgot the translation lets return the given string instead
        return text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the question above, I found out it was due to Java requiring the values-in file instead of values-id for indonesian.

The same goes for yiddish and hebrew, if you ever seem to have the same issue that I had.

Comment: Why 'in' and not 'id' ? The standard should be 'id'.

Comment: I'm not working on the Android project. Don't ask me.